# Русские или другие символы в EmguCV?

Tags: символы, emgucv

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> testFrame;  
MCvFont font = new MCvFont(FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5d, 0.5d);   
testFrame.Draw("Привет!, Gruß, ಹೈ, ", ref font, new Point(100, 100), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));
```

**Вопрос:** как можно вывести русские или другие символы в *EmguCV* ?